# How to clear a Notifications in admin panel using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am new in PHP and Ajax please I need some help

This is my some code

```
<div class="dropdown-item noti-title">
  <h6 class="m-0"><span class="float-right"><a href="" onClick="clearNotify()" class="text-dark"><small>Clear All</small></a> </span>Notification</h6>
</div>
```

When click on clear then notifications not clear its still showing and in database table there is one field is **isclear** and notifications showing in this condition that **isclear = 0** and **isclear = 1** in this condtion notifications is not showing.

This ajax calling code

```
<script>
                   function clearNotify()
                   {

                       $.ajax({ 
                       url: 'ajaxfiles/clear_notifications.php',
                       type: 'post',
                    success: function(output) {

              }
      });

                       }
                   </script>
```

clear_notifications.php

```
<? include '../common/config.php';
   session_start();
   $user_id = $_SESSION["admin"];

     if($_POST)
    {
      $clear_notifications = $db->updateCondition(array("isclear"=>"1"),PREFIX."users_notification","user_id like '%$user_id%'");

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Lots of potential gotchas here.  Does the server support the short_open_tag for PHP?  Have you tested clear_notifications.php with "if (true)" instead of "if ($_POST)"?  What do you see going on in the browser console when the AJAX is executed?

Comment: in console its showing nothing

Comment: So, the AJAX call isn't even being sent?  What if you run clearNotify() in console?

Comment: The console should show XHR requests in any circumstance.

Comment: thank you kevin now its working when I write if (true)

Comment: OK, so you need to see why it's not working with if($_POST).  I might suggest, just to ward off any bugs, you send a variable in the POST array and test for it being set in your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

**AJAX** seems ok, check your clear_notifications.php.